# Ajax contact form not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using an ajax contact form, however it does not seem to work properly. As soon as I try to submit the form I get the "Please fill in all fields" message even though I've filled them all out.

Here my current form code:

```
    <form method="get" action="mail.php">

    <input name="fname" type="text" value="Enter your First Name here..." id="fname" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter your First Name here...') this.value = ''"/>
    <input name="lname" type="text" value="Enter your Last Name here..." id="lname" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter your Last Name here...') this.value = ''"/>
    <input name="cname" type="text" value="Enter your Company Name here..." id="cname" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter your Company Name here...') this.value = ''"/>
    <input name="web" type="text" value="Enter your Website here..." id="web" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter your Website here...') this.value = ''"/>
    <input name="email" type="text" value="Enter your E-mail here..." id="email" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter your E-mail here...') this.value = ''"/>
    <input name="phone" type="text" value="Enter your Phone Number here..." id="phone" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter your Phone Number here...') this.value = ''"/>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter your message here...') this.value = ''" rows="" cols="">Enter your message here...</textarea>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
    <div id="response" style="float:right">
    <p></p>
    </div>

    </form>
```

Content of my mail.php:

```
    <?php

    if ($_GET['fname'] == "" || $_GET['lname'] == "" || $_GET['cname'] == "" || $_GET['web'] == "" || $_GET['phone'] == "" ||  $_GET['email'] == "" || $_GET['message'] == "") {
        echo 'Please fill in all fields!';
        exit;
    }

    if (strlen($_GET['fname']) < 3) {
        echo 'Your name should be atleast 3 characters long!';
        exit;
    }

    if (strlen($_GET['lname']) < 3) {
        echo 'Your name should be atleast 3 characters long!';
        exit;
    }

    if (strlen($_GET['cname']) < 3) {
        echo 'Your name should be atleast 3 characters long!';
        exit;
    }

    if (strlen($_GET['web']) < 3) {
        echo 'Your name should be atleast 3 characters long!';
        exit;
    }

    if (strlen($_GET['phone']) < 3) {
        echo 'Your name should be atleast 3 characters long!';
        exit;
    }

    if (!preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([\.a-zA-Z0-9_-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6})$/", $_GET['email'])) {
        echo 'Please enter a valid email address!'; 
        exit;
    }

    if (strlen($_GET['message']) < 10) {
        echo 'Your message should be atleast 10 characters long!';
        exit;
    }

    $to = 'my@email.com';

    $name = stripslashes($_GET['name']);
    $email = stripslashes($_GET['email']);

    $subject  = "Contact request";
    $msg  = "From:".$name."\r\n";
    $msg .= "e-Mail:".$email."\r\n";
    $msg .= "Subject:".$subject."\r\n\n";
    $msg .= "---Message--- \r\n".nl2br(stripslashes($_GET['message']))."\r\n\n";

    $mail = mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From:".$email);

    if($mail) {
        echo 'We will be in touch shortly!';
    } else {
        echo 'Error: Message could not be sent!';
    }

    ?>
```

Last but not least the ajax.js

```
     $(function() {
        $("input#submit").click( 
            function() {
                $('#response p').empty().append("<img src='img/ajax-loader.gif' />");

                var fname = $("#fname").val();  
                var lname = $("#lname").val();
                var cname = $("#cname").val(); 
                var web = $("#web").val();  
                var email = $("#email").val(); 
                var phone = $("#phone").val(); 
                var message = $("#message").val(); 

                var dataString = 'fname='+ fname + 'lname='+ lname + 'cname='+ cname + 'web='+ web + '&email=' + email + 'phone='+ phone + '&message=' + message;  

                $.ajax({

                    url: "mail.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function(responseText) {

                         $('#response p').empty().append(responseText);
                         }
                     });

            return false;

        });
      });
```

Any idea what is wrong here? Some expert advice would be truly helpful.

Comment: Inspect the contents of `$_GET`.. `var_dump($_GET);` Your formm looks ok...

Comment: You might want to use `filter_var($_GET['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` to really validate your email.

Comment: You might want to look into using the placeholder attribute available in most modern browsers for your onfocus effect.

Comment: Random... but why not validate with Javascript?

Comment: it seems working if u fill all the fields

Comment: I have forgotten to add the third file that is part of this form - kindly find my updated post.

Comment: My suggestion is to use Jquery Ajax that this old one.

Comment: For testing purposes I've tried to run the script without the JS file and it seems to validate fine - once the JS is included as well it goes back to the "Fill in all fields" error , so I reckon the problem must be definitely in there. Any ideas how I can get this fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to prepend every parameter with an `&` while building your `dataString`

```
var dataString = 'fname='+ fname + '&lname='+ lname + '&cname='+ cname + '&web='+ web + '&email=' + email + '&phone='+ phone + '&message=' + message;
```

In your code you did this only for `email` and `message`.